# Перевод функции arcTo -> bezier

Tags: canvas, алгоритм

Как бы превратить arcTo (стандартная функция postScript, да и не только, например в HTML5Canvas она есть) с параметрами x1, y1, x2, y2, radius в кривую Безье?

Comment: Вопрос не закрыт :). Нужен arcTo, а не arc, т.е. именно функция, соединяющая эллиптической кривой 2 точки.

Comment: Кажется, ответ в Google Closure: http://closure-library.googlecode.com/svn/docs/closure_goog_graphics_path.js.source.html

Вопрос закрыт :)

Comment: Оказалось, достаточно было посмотреть на arcTo поближе) это практически та же кривая Безье.

Answer (score 2):

Вспомнить тригонометрию : ) Бился с аналогичным вопросом в [Processing](http://www.processing.org/). Вопрос популярный и решения [гуглятся](https://www.google.com/search?q=bezier+arc). Например, даже [с интерактивным примером](http://hansmuller-flex.blogspot.com/2011/04/approximating-circular-arc-with-cubic.html).

Comment: Спасибо, тоже пригодится, но мне нужно было немножко другое. Не arc, а arcTo.

Answer (score 1):

Занимался аналогичным вопросом. Вот в помощь 
[картинка в svg](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B1qDNBsdY08mYlprQmlCeG1ESWs) для вычисления расстояния (*l*) до контрольной точки, тоже не для эллипса к сожалению, но думаю можно как-нибудь обобщить.

Comment: Ну это же не то. С тригонометрией у меня неплохо, с функцией arc я разберусь. Именно она рисует эллиптическую кривую. А вот arcTo рисует немного другую кривую. Объяснить сложно, поисковик в помощь.

Comment: +Keyten спасибо, мне помощь по PS пока не требуется